# Find files without underscore in their filename with regex

Tags: regex, linux, find

Under a directory, there are files with underscore in their filenames. I want to get such files and print them on screen.
The command I used is:

```
find ./ -type f -name '[a-z0-9]*\.java'
```

But I can still get the file `./a_b.java` on screen.
Could you tell me what's wrong with my regex?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not a regex, it's a pattern. `*` means "any characters", as in `ls *`. Use `-regex` instead of `-name` to actually use a regex, but note that it has to match the whole path, not just the filename.

```
find . -type f -regex '.*/[a-z0-9]*\.java'
```

Answer (score 0):

`-name` in `find` is a `glob` pattern.  Check the man page when you're unsure:

```
   -name pattern
          Base of file name (the path with the leading directories removed) matches  shell  pattern  pattern.   Because  the  leading  directories  are
          removed,  the file names considered for a match with -name will never include a slash, so `-name a/b' will never match anything (you probably
          need to use -path instead).  A warning is issued if you try to do  this,  unless  the  environment  variable  POSIXLY_CORRECT  is  set.   The
          metacharacters  (`*',  `?',  and  `[]') match a `.' at the start of the base name (this is a change in findutils-4.2.2; see section STANDARDS
          CONFORMANCE below).  To ignore a directory and the files under it, use -prune; see an example in the description of -path.   Braces  are  not
          recognised  as  being  special,  despite the fact that some shells including Bash imbue braces with a special meaning in shell patterns.  The
          filename matching is performed with the use of the fnmatch(3) library function.   Don't forget to enclose the pattern in quotes in  order  to
          protect it from expansion by the shell.
```